# indexedDB testing Jeste Enzyme -TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Tags: testing, jestjs, enzyme, indexeddb

Aplication working fine but when i test then it crashed.

this is pice of code where is something wrong.. i think

```html
componentDidMount = async() => {
    try{
      const request = await window.indexedDB.open("QuestionData",1)

      request.onsuccess = (event) => {
        const db = request.result;
        const transaction = db.transaction('Questions' , "readwrite");
        const store = transaction.objectStore('Questions');
  
        const get = store.get(1)
        get.onsuccess = () =>{ 
          this.setState({
            data: get.result.data
          })
        }
      }

    }catch(err){console.log(err)}
  }
```

and this is a pice of test

```html
test('should render btn', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />)
  const btn = wrapper.find('.btn')
  expect(btn.length).toBe(1)
})
```

now Error !

> console.log src/App.js:36
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Comment: To start with, `indexedDB.open` does not return a promise, you can only await a promise

Comment: so what i should do?

Comment: Can you please spend more time preparing your question, such as by fixing grammatical and spelling errors. Please spend more time explaining your problem so that your question is clearer. You will be more likely to get help on stackoverflow if it shows you carefully prepared your question.